# Finding Y values on a circle

Tags: geometry-surface, arduino-c++

I want to find the Y values on a circle. Given is the center, the radius and some X values.
e.g. : center is 10,10, radius is 5. What is the Y value if X=(centerX - radius), X=centerX - radius +1, ... X = centerX + radius. 
I do understand that there will be 2 results for each X.
I need this equation to draw a circle on a LED matrix using an Arduino (C++)

Starting from the formula

```
(x-a)² + (y-b)² = r²
```

where

```
r = radius
a = centerX
b = centerY
x = x coordinate of point on circle
y = y coordinate of point on circle
```

The equation for y should be :

```
y = sq(r²-x² + 2a - a² + 2b - b²)
```

but I don't get a circle on my matrix ...
When I calculate y manually for some x values, I mostly come to a negative number before I take the square root. And of course a square root from a negative number does not exist.
Of course the compiler does not give any error messages.

```
y = sq((r * r) - (x * x) + (2 * a) - (a * a) + (2 * b) - (b * b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold it, hold it ! :)
Let me first correct my code ...
instead of using "sq", I should have used "**sqrt**"...
I'll get back here soon to let you know if this was the culprit ...
thanks to those who read and tried to find a solution ...

Oh ... Also found a flaw in my equation ...
(x-a)² + (y-b)² = r²

(y-b)² = r² - (x-a)²  (OK?)

y² - 2by + b² =  r² - (x-a)²    (OK?)

y² - 2by =  r² - (x-a)²  -b²     (OK?)

Now we have y twice on the left... I can't transfer one of the y's to the right 'cause the result would be IN the equation, right ?
So,what now ???

Answer (score 0):

You should do sqrt(r^2 - (X-a)^2) + b

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501598/define-y-value-from-the-equation-of-circle)

basicly you have

(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2

=> (y-b)^2 = r^2 - (x-a)^2

=> (y-b) = +- sqrt(r^2 - (x-a)^2)

=> y = b +- sqrt(r^2 - (x-a)^2)